# Converting multi-side PDF to PPT

Tags: pdf, document-converter, powerpoint

I have a handout in PDF which has 4 slides in a page like [this](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs143/lectures/lecture01.pdf).

[image]

How do I convert it to a PPT with just one slide per page?